# Google Maps API: Bring up address selections as you type

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm looking to create a web application that starts to suggest home addresses as you type.  For instance, imagine a pizza delivery company, where you start typing in your address, "1279", and beneath the box it brings up 1279's in the US for people to choose from, like:

```
1279 Main Street, St. Louis, MO
1279 Tree Street, Baltimore, MD
```

In this way, it would really mirror `maps.google.com` in bringing up suggestions as you type.

I've looked through the Google Places and Maps APIs without much success.  The GeoCoding one works OK by passing an address parameter through, but often returns no results or really bad ones... nothing like `maps.google.com`. Plus they're difficult to parse. (The address parts parameters aren't always consistent, meaning that I have to send the formatted address through another parser... not a deal-breaker though.)

Anyone else have any suggestions out there?  Thanks! Jeremy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can improve the Places autocomplete results by passing `bounds` option when creating it. The example binds it to the map viewport:

```js
autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
```

In this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/23/) I hardcoded the continental US bounds (plus some of Mexico and Canada)

```js
var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,
    {bounds: new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        new google.maps.LatLng(23.730197707069532, -126.14240169525146), 
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.1805258484942, -65.32208919525146)) }
);
```

Comment: I was with the GeoCoding one to no avail.  I think the general point you both make is that I need to use the autocomplete API, which somehow I managed to overlook.  Taking a look now.  Thanks!

Comment: I didn't know there were several options. I found geo-autocomplete and  a jQuery plugin. You should try them and see which works best!

Comment: Thanks. Your post (and others) led me to the autocomplete API (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/autocomplete), and your demo will help a lot in further development.